# How to create tenant programmatically by Office 365 API client libraries

Tags: windows-store-apps, office365

I was developing a windows store app integrate with Office 365 API client libraries, But I can't find a interface in office365 api can be used to create a new tenant? Is there any method that can create tenant programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The Office 365 APIs do not allow you to provision new tenants at this time. If you'd like to see this feature please let the team know at the [Office/SharePoint developer UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

Comment: I am curious if the api to create a new tenant is now available?